# symfony2: FOSElasticaBundle class included in AppKernel can not be found

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

i installed FOSElasticaBundle using Composer, After that as per the given instruction on
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle
i registered FOSElasticaBundle Class in Appkernel.php file, demo code is as following

```
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),
    );
}
```

But the Problem is after registering `new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),` in the AppKernel.php file. i am trying to run Symfony command from netbeans but it is showing Error

> Fatal error: Class 'FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle' not found in
>   AppKernel.php file

Please Give me Some Solution for this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Which version have you tried installing? Did it get installed in you `vendor` directory after all?

Comment: i installed using "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.0.*@dev".
and i have got the elastica-bundle in vendor directory.

Comment: Try opening file `FOSElasticaBundle`... which namespace is specified? Have you tried running `composer update "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle"`?

Comment: thanks i found solution i fixed the issue with declaring it into 
autoload.php file
$loader->add('FOS', __DIR__.'/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS');

Comment: Which version of Symfony2 are you using? Using `autoload.php` to map namespaces to directories - it sounds to me like 2.0?

Comment: i am using symfony 2.3.7

Comment: Sorry about my comment. Maybe sounded a bit rude... wasn't my intention :) Anyhow, it is weird you had to add map namespace manually...

Comment: ... you should probably add the solution yourself. Maybe someone else stumbles upon the same issue ;)

Comment: Why are you using manual mapping in the autoloader? You could use the --optimize-autoloader option in composer install/update commands. You can also use the APC autoloader to boost the autoloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

After doing complete configuration of FosElasticaBundle.

Add this line

```
$loader->add('FOS', DIR.'/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/FOS');
```

into your app/autoloader.php file.
that's work for me.

thank you.